# Sort with one element at the end

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects and I want to sort it alphabetically by an attribute. But I want to add an exception rule if this attribute matches a specific string. For example:

```
public class Car {
  String name;
}
```

```
List<Car> cars = asList(
    new Car("Unassigned"), 
    new Car("Nissan"), 
    new Car("Yamaha"), 
    new Car("Honda"));

List<Car> sortedCars = cars
  .stream
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getName))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `cars.name == "Unassigned"` then this car should remain at the end of the list and the result would be:

```
[Car<Honda>, Car<Nissan>, Car<Yamaha>, Car<Unassigned>]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
  List<Car> sortedCars = cars
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
            Car::getName,
            Comparator.comparing((String x) -> x.equals("Unassigned"))
                      .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are a lot of things going on here. First I am using `Comparator.comparing(Function, Comparator)`; then `(String x) -> x.equals("Unassigned")` which actually compares a `Boolean` (that is `Comparable`); then the fact that `(String x)` is used - as this type witness is used to correctly infer the types...

Comment: Clever! But I think that the trick with `comparing((String x) -> x.equals("Unassigned"))` is so tricky that it warrants an explanatory comment in the code, it it where to be used in production...

Comment: @Lii which is left as an exercise to the reader... I mentioned it sorts a `Boolean` (that is `Comparable`), that should provide the proper direction.

Comment: *Clever* indeed.

Answer (score 10):

The most direct and and easy-to-read solution is probably to write a custom comparator that implements your sorting logic.

You can still use the `Comparator.comparing` method to make it a bit prettier, though:

```
public static final String UNASSIGNED = "Unassigned";

List<Car> cars = List.of(
    new Car("Unassigned"), 
    new Car("Nissan"), 
    new Car("Yamaha"), 
    new Car("Honda"));

List<Car> sortedCars = cars.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getName, (name1, name2) -> {
            if (name1.equals(name2)) return 0;
            if (name1.equals(UNASSIGNED)) return 1;
            if (name2.equals(UNASSIGNED)) return -1;
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }))
    .collect(toList());
```

---

It is possible to extract the "at-the-end" functionality to a separate comparable combinator method. Like this:

```
List<Car> sortedCars = cars.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getName, withValueAtEnd(UNASSIGNED)))
    .collect(toList());

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<T> withValueAtEnd(T atEnd) {
  return withValueAtEnd(atEnd, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

public static <T> Comparator<T> withValueAtEnd(T atEnd, Comparator<T> c) {
    return (a, b) -> {
        if (a.equals(atEnd)) return 1;
        if (b.equals(atEnd)) return -1;
        return c.compare(a, b);
    };
}
```

---

Also, it's good style to use a named constant for special values like your `"Unassigned"`.

---

Also, note that if you don't need to keep the unsorted `cars` list, then you can sort that list in place instead of using a stream:

```
cars.sort(UNASSIGNED_COMPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to possibly do that would be using partitioning as:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Car>> partitionedCars = cars
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> a.getName().equals("Unassigned")));

List<Car> sortedCars = Stream.concat(partitionedCars.get(Boolean.FALSE).stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getName)), partitionedCars.get(Boolean.TRUE).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this is ingenious, but wasteful or resources... of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace "Unassigned" with an end-of-alphabet string in your comparator.

```
Comparator.comparing(car -> car.getName().equals("Unassigned") ? "ZZZ" : car.getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just remove all instances of "Unassigned" and add however many to the end of the `List` after. For example:

```
int numberOfUnassigned = 0;
for (Iterator<Car> iterator = sortedCars.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String str = iterator.next().getName();
    if (str.equals("Unassigned")) {
        iterator.remove();
        numberOfUnassigned++;
    }
}
```

And then add the number of `numberOfUnassigned` to the end.